# How to use Python decord library to seek by timestamp instead of by frame index?

Tags: python, video, time, frames

[Decord](https://github.com/dmlc/decord/) allows to seek a video frame from a file using indices, like:

```py
video_reader = decord.VideoReader(video_path)
frames = video_reader.get_batch(indices)
```

How can I do the same if I have timestamps (with the unit second)?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the timestamp of each frame (averaging its start and end times), then find the closest one:

```py
from typing import Sequence, Union

import decord
import numpy as np


def time_to_indices(video_reader: decord.VideoReader, time: Union[float, Sequence[float]]) -> np.ndarray:
    times = video_reader.get_frame_timestamp(range(len(video_reader))).mean(-1)
    indices = np.searchsorted(times, time)
    # Use `np.bitwise_or` so it works both with scalars and numpy arrays.
    return np.where(np.bitwise_or(indices == 0, times[indices] - time <= time - times[indices - 1]), indices,
                    indices - 1)

frames = video_reader.get_batch(time_to_indices(indices))
```

Note the VideoReader C object (not the Python one) is loaded already with all the frame timestamps from the initialization. And we take advantage of the fact that they should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

PyTrochVideo uses decord as its video decoding backend, and provides timestamp reading:

```
from pytorchvideo.data.encoded_video import EncodedVideo

start_sec = 0
end_sec = start_sec + clip_duration

video = EncodedVideo.from_path(video_path)
video_data = video.get_clip(start_sec=start_sec, end_sec=end_sec)
```

The tutorial is at https://pytorchvideo.org/docs/tutorial_torchhub_inference